# Transaction: 6 hours and 0 confirmations

Tags: transaction-confirmation

Is there others than me experiencing a slow XMR chain?
It has been 6 hours and 0 confirmations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rush hour at the moment. Eventually blocksize will grow big enough to confirm all the transactions - including yours.

See how it develops here: http://moneroblocks.info/stats/block-medians

In the meantime, you could use a higher fee for "mission critical" TX-es which usually skips the line. If everyone wanted to skip the line at the same time, then the blocks would grow even faster. Note that the "high priority" may be too expensive for some - about 6$. Check the fees here: https://www.monero.how/monero-transaction-fee-calculator